# Running a Multi-service docker compose script in Google Compute Engine VM

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform, docker-compose, gcloud

I have a `docker-compose.yml` file which specifies *two* services `aaa` and `bbb` as follows,

```
version: "3.4"

services:
  aaa:
    platform: linux/amd64
    build: .
    image: aaa
    environment:
      - ENV_VAR=1
    volumes:
      - ./data:/root/data
    ports:
      - 5900:5900
    restart: on-failure
  
  bbb:
    image: bbb
    build: ./service_directory
    platform: linux/amd64
    environment:
      - PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1
    volumes:
      - ./data:/root/data
    ports:
      - 5901:5901
    restart: on-failure
    depends_on:
      - aaa
```

I'm hoping to run both the above services simultaenously on a google cloud machine VM via `cloudbuild.yaml` which reads,

```
steps:
- name: 'gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/docker-compose'
  args: ['up']
  tags: ['cloud-builders-community']
```

My deployment script looks like

```
#!/bin/bash

container=mycontainer # container name
pid=my-nginx-363907 # process id
zone=us-west4-b
instance=instance-${zone} # instance name

gcloud builds submit \
--tag gcr.io/${pid}/${container} \
--project=${pid}

gcloud compute instances create-with-container ${instance} \
--zone=${zone} \
--tags=http-server,https-server \
--machine-type=e2-micro \
--container-image gcr.io/${pid}/${container} \
--project=${pid}

gcloud compute instances list --project=${pid}
```

Here's my directory structure:

```
project
|  cloudbuild.yaml
|  docker-compose.yml
|  Dockerfile
|
|--service_directory
   |
   |--Dockerfile
```

The `docker compose up` command does kick in, but it appears to build only service `aaa`, and not `bbb`. What's worse is that the service `aaa` does not actually appear to run or have been installed in the VM instance. This is despite messages of apparent success:

```
ID                                    CREATE_TIME                DURATION  SOURCE                                                                                         IMAGES                                     STATUS
ab4785dd-7c4e-413d-acf6-1fdc64308387  2022-09-29T11:25:28+00:00  6M17S     gs://my-nginx-363907_cloudbuild/source/1664450585.644241-04488e692b644a6186d922270dfbe667.tgz  gcr.io/my-nginx-363907/aaa (+1 more)  SUCCESS
```

Can someone please explain how to run both the services on Google Cloud Compute Engine VM as specified by the `docker-compose.yml` file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably need not use [Cloud Build](https://cloud.google.com/build) if you just want to run Docker Compose.

Cloud Build is often used (but not limited to) building container images.

You could (but need not) use Cloud Build to build the 2 container images that your `docker-compose.yaml` uses (`aaa`, `bbb`) but you would need to revise the `cloudbuild.yaml` to just perform the `build` and `push` steps and then you'd need to revise `docker-compose.yaml` to consume the images produced by Cloud Build.

I think you should create a Compute Engine VM ensure that Docker, Docker Compose and your build content (`.`) are available and then run your `docker-compose.yaml` as you would on any Linux machine.